# Find all possible patters in list of no and the position of the pattern break

Tags: python, time-series, subsequence, longest-substring

input has list of nos
output has all the possible pattern  occurring and the position where the pattern break

```
input

[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,10,5,6,4,5,6,8,4,5,6,12,2,3]

output

[1,2,3]: 10th position and 14th

[4,5,6]:20th position and 24th
```

[1,2,3] and [4,5,6] all possible patter
the position where the pattern breaks 10,14 for [1,2,3] and 20 and 24 for [4,5,6]

Comment: Bit of a whiff of homework off this one.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: checking if any algorithm or any package already exists or not that I can take help of

Comment: What can be the maximum length of pattern?

Comment: no limit, I dont care about the time and space complexity here ,trying to find something that can work for now

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import more_itertools as mit
from ast import literal_eval
l= [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,10,5,6,4,5,6,8,4,5,6,12,2,3]
```

#split the list by sequences

```
seq = [list(group) for group in mit.consecutive_groups(l)]
```

#find duplicate lists

```
uni = set([str(s) for s in seq if seq.count(s)>1])
```

#create new dictionary with empty lists to store output

```
dic = {u:[] for u in uni}
```

#main code, apply nested loop over `uni` and `seq`, and compare the both lists, *in simple term first try to the next not same list from `[1,2,3]` so first outcome will be `[1,2,3,4]` take the `last element 4` and find the `index value` of it from input list `plus 1` will be the output.*

```
[dic[v].append(l.index(s[-1])+1) for i, v in enumerate(uni) for j, s in enumerate(seq) if str(seq[j-1])==v and s!=literal_eval(v)]
```

**Output:**

```
{'[1, 2, 3]': [10, 14], '[4, 5, 6]': [20, 24]}
```